# onBackPressed() should call previous activity's onBackPressed()

Tags: android, onbackpressed, activity-stack

So here is the problem, I perform A → B and from B I do B → C , now when the back button is pressed in C I want to go back to A. so at start the flow is A → B → C but I want to clear B when I start C so when back pressed from C I go back to A.
I know I can start A from  C and CLEAR_TOP but I am looking for another alternative if there is one.

Thank You

Comment: What about calling `finish()` in `Activity` B when going to `Activity` C? Of course call `finish()` after `startActivity`.

Comment: Inside B, call `finish()` after starting C.

Comment: For confirming I have to Ask this A,B and C are fragments in same activity ?

Comment: call finish() method inside of B activity.
you can call finish() below startActivity(intent) method.

Comment: @Nithinlal no these are activities.

Comment: this was pretty trivial, it worked :)

Comment: Then i post the answer for you question pls check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can call finish(); after you start intent on B .

Answer (score 3):

You just need to call `finish()`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 2):

call `finish();` after passing Intent on Activity you don't want to open on back press.

Answer (score 2):

```
    //FROM A TO B
    Intent A = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
    startActivity(A);

    //FROM B TO C
    Intent B = new Intent(B.this,C.class);
    startActivity(B);
    finish();

    //FROM C TO A
    onBackPressed(); you can go directly to A.
```

hope this may help u.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

If you call finish() after start C Activity, in B Activity. You can remove B Activity from stack. So if you press back in C, you will see A Activity.